# Determining the Growth Function

Tags: java, time-complexity

My professor has given our class this assignment with little explanation. Given a snip-it of code to determine both the big-O notation and the growth function. I understand the big-O part but am sort of lost on the growth function part.

```
    for (int count = 0; count < n; count ++) {
   for (int count2 = 0; count2 < n; count2 = count2 * 2) {
      System.out.println(count, count2);
   }
}
```

This is what we are given. An explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right code? Because this will get stuck in an infinite loop (count2 will always have the value of 0, 0*2 = 0)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo that should be  int count2=1;

Answer (score 1):

While Maljam is correct about it being an infinite loop, by making the assumption that both start at 1 and are <= n:

The **outer for-loop** will make the inner for-loop occur:

> n-1 times

The **inner for-loop** will make the Sysout statement run approximately (by flooring the function):

> log_2(n) times

Thus, the result of the big-O is the product of those two:

> O((n-1)(log_2(n)))

Or more simply:

> O(nlogn)

Comment: I understood that part but I'm not sure what is meant by growth function

Comment: While I've never heard of the specific term "growth function", I would assume that the answer would be simply nlogn.